# whats the problem with this awk code - mawk slower than gawk

Tags: bash, awk

can somebody explain, why execution with mawk takes 1.6s with this code against execution with gawk takes 0.078ms.
I wanted to change to mawk, because of better speed, but whats the problem with this awk code?

```sh
#!/bin/bash
declare g_RV="" g_ESC=$'\x1b'
#-- call:        g_SO_FTS_convFromFTI_awk [FTI text STR]
#-- description: converts a Format Tags Inside text to a Format Tags Simple text - for long text
#--              Look at Internal Data Formats - FTS, FTI
#-- parameters:  $1 ... FTI text STR - FTI text to convert
#-- returnValue: written to g_RV - STR ... the converted FTS text
#-- depends on:  variables - g_RV, g_ESC
function g_SO_FTS_convFromFTI_awk ()
    {
    #-- awk script begin
    g_RV=$(gawk \
'   BEGIN { RS="^$"; output=""}
    { #-- var textPart, textParts, textParts_l, i, sI, bSlash
        textParts_l=split($0,textParts,">");
        for (i=1; i<textParts_l; i++) {
            textPart=textParts[i]; bSlashn=-1;
            if (match(textPart,/<[^\n<]*$/)) {
                bSlashn=0; sI=RSTART-1; while (substr(textPart,sI,1) == "\\") { bSlashn++; sI--; if (sI<1) break; }}
            if (bSlashn % 2 == 0) output=output substr(textPart,1,RSTART-1) "'"$g_ESC"'" substr(textPart,RSTART) ">";
            else output=output textPart ">"; }
        output=output textParts[textParts_l]; } #-- last textPart can only contain data text without format tag or a nullstring
    END {gsub(/\\</,"<",output); gsub(/\\\\/,"\\",output); printf "%s", output }' <<< $1";") #-- here strings trailing new line, will be removed by command substitution
    g_RV=${g_RV:1:-1} #-- cut off ; which was added before to consider possible trailing new lines
    #-- awk script end
    }
a=$'\n'$'\n'"Hello <b:i>World"$'\n'$'\n'"</b:/i><color 42;70;32:darkgrey>This is a Test<color -1:-1> <bm>green red blue</bm> <cu>this is curly underline <u>normal underline</all>jjj"
b="";
for ((i=0;i<2000;i++));do b+=$a;done
time g_SO_FTS_convFromFTI_awk "$b";
```

i think the problem is this line

```
output=output substr(textPart,1,RSTART-1) "'"$g_ESC"'" substr(textPart,RSTART) ">";
```

and especially adding everything to the variable output and then print it at the end.
the next version below is now fast, not writing everything to variable output, but print with every loop, although i now call two times gsub function in every loop, i'm faster than with gawk -0.037ms

```
function g_SO_FTS_convFromFTI_awkA ()
    {
    #-- awk script begin
    g_RV=$(mawk \
'   BEGIN { RS="^$";}
    { #-- var output, textPart, textParts, textParts_l, i, sI, bSlash
        textParts_l=split($0,textParts,">");
        for (i=1; i<textParts_l; i++) {
            textPart=textParts[i]; bSlashn=-1;
            if (match(textPart,/<[^\n<]*$/)) {
                bSlashn=0; sI=RSTART-1; while (substr(textPart,sI,1) == "\\") { bSlashn++; sI--; if (sI<1) break; }}
            if (bSlashn % 2 == 0) output=substr(textPart,1,RSTART-1) "'"$g_ESC"'" substr(textPart,RSTART) ">";
            else output=textPart ">";
            gsub(/\\</,"<",output); gsub(/\\\\/,"\\",output); printf "%s", output }

        output=textParts[textParts_l];  #-- last textPart can only contain data text without format tag
        gsub(/\\</,"<",output); gsub(/\\\\/,"\\",output); printf "%s", output } ' <<< $1";") #-- here strings trailing new line, will be removed by command substitution
    g_RV=${g_RV:1:-1} #-- cut off ; which was added before to consider possible trailing new lines
    #-- awk script end
    }
```

but still dont know why, does the output variable get too big or is string addition in mawk generally slow...?.....

---

Edit by Ed Morton: here's the first awk script above (they may both be the same, idk) formatted by `gawk -o-` to be readable:

```
BEGIN {
        RS = "^$"
        output = ""
}

{
        #-- var textPart, textParts, textParts_l, i, sI, bSlash
        textParts_l = split($0, textParts, ">")
        for (i = 1; i < textParts_l; i++) {
                textPart = textParts[i]
                bSlashn = -1
                if (match(textPart, /<[^\n<]*$/)) {
                        bSlashn = 0
                        sI = RSTART - 1
                        while (substr(textPart, sI, 1) == "\\") {
                                bSlashn++
                                sI--
                                if (sI < 1) {
                                        break
                                }
                        }
                }
                if (bSlashn % 2 == 0) {
                        output = output substr(textPart, 1, RSTART - 1) "'"$g_ESC"'" substr(textPart, RSTART) ">"
                } else {
                        output = output textPart ">"
                }
        }
        output = output textParts[textParts_l]
}

#-- last textPart can only contain data text without format tag or a nullstring
END {
        gsub(/\\</, "<", output)
        gsub(/\\\\/, "\\", output)
        printf "%s", output
}
```

Comment: Probably nothing to do with your time issue but `/<[^\n<]*/` is very strange. It matches any string containing `<`, so why not simply `/</`?

Comment: the text contains format tags <.....> and is splitted in textparts at char >. this textparts are examined for <......   this is not allowed <bold<kll or this is not allowed <bold\nkll. will not be recognized. i forget the $ sign /<[^\n<]*$/ , which is in the newly function but it seems that i copied the old function in here, but i have still the time difference problem, and cant find the mistake.

Comment: So, please, edit your answer and fix it.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet fixed it, and think adding everything to the variable output and print the complete variable output at the end is the problem, but still dont know why.

Comment: the target is to put a g_ESC character which ASCII escape at the begin of every format tag  <.....> becomes g_ESC<.....>  and unescape \< to < and \\ to \ only in data text not in the format tag  (data text is the text outside the format tags)

Comment: `foo = foo "bar"` is slow in any awk, often slower than input/output, because awk has to allocate enough memory for the resulting concatenated string, put that resulting string into that new location, free the old memory and change the variable to point to the new location. There's probably other issues with your cod too but it's too tightly crammed together to be readable. YMMV with trying to use `RS="^$"` in mawk though as multi-char RS is a gawk-extension. I THINK it may have been picked up by `mawk2` but not the original `mawk` and you didn't say which version you use.

Comment: If you [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output that demonstrate whatever it is you're trying to do then we can help you write an efficient, portable (if you like) script to do it. The problem with writing a portable script so you can run it in mawk as well as gawk is  that we'd then need to not use gawk extensions which could make the result slower than necessary when run in gawk - a gawk-specific script run in gawk may be faster than a portable script run in mawk.

Comment: By the way - once upon a time mawk was a minimal-featured awk designed for speed and so ran faster than gawk. Today mawk has picked up some of gawk's extensions (e.g. `gensub()`) and gawk's execution speed has improved drastically so I'm not sure you'd really see much difference in speed between modern releases of the 2. Also, if gawk is fast enough for your needs then don't worry about trying some other tool as gawk has the most features/functionality and best support.

Comment: hi ed i use GNU Awk 5.0.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.2.0)
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2019 Free Software Foundation.
mawk 1.3.4 20200120
Copyright 2008-2019,2020, Thomas E. Dickey
Copyright 1991-1996,2014, Michael D. Brennan
on Linux Mint System,
and as reference for mawk https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html
and the reference for gawk i got from gnu project

Comment: So you mean its better to stay on , and write for gawk?

Comment: To inform someone who posted a comment that you left a reply for them you use `@` then their user name, e.g. `@edmorton`, to tag it, you can't just say "hi ed", it's just dumb luck I stumbled across your comment above. Yes, that's what I'd do since gawk is very fast and has a lot of features.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
match(textPart,/<[^\n<]*/)
```

to

```
match(textPart,/[<][^\n<]+?/)
```

and see if that helps with `mawk`. ps : whenever possible, encapsulate `printf("%s", str)`

If you're trying to capture tags, and also handle errorneous data, perhaps maybe :

```
echo ' test<abc123>april<bye<hi>456' \
 \
 | mawk2 ' gsub(/[<][^\n<>]+?[>]/,"\f{ & }\f") { 
    
    print
        ____=split($(_<_),__,\
                            "[\f][{][ ][<]|[>][ ][}][\f]")
    for(___=_+=_=_~_;_<____;_+=___) {
       printf(" Row %.f tag %.f : %s\n",NR,_/___,__[_]) } }'

 test
     { <abc123> }
                 april<bye
                          { <hi> }
                                  456
 Row 1 tag 1 : abc123
 Row 1 tag 2 : hi
```

Here, the tag and tag contents of `abc123` and `hi` are properly captured, while erroneous `bye` isn't.